French Drain Next to patio
Please let me know if this will work. There are two channel drains connected with a corrugated pipe. We get lts of standing water around this area. My concern is water is now going to make its way under the patio concrete slab? thank you



The whole point of the drains is to take water away from the patio slab.
While I personally would use non-corrugated pipe (the runs appear to be straight, and smooth rigid pipe traps less dirt inside it) it's going to reduce, not increase, the incidence of water under the slab.
Water headed under the slab will be intercepted and removed by the drains, assuming that they slope correctly to move water and are kept clear. If they clog up, it will be no worse that it was without drains at all, but not letting them clog is obviously the better choice, so maintain them by removing debris as it accumulates.
